# How to switch a stream of events between "output devices" in rxjs

Tags: rxjs

I have one rxjs subject that is a stream of WebMidi notes (a note is an array of numbers), and another subject that is a stream of selected midi output devices:

```
const midiOutputDeviceSubject$ = new Subject<WebMidi.MIDIOutput>();
const midiNoteStream$ = new Subject<number[]>();
```

I want to send a NEW device to the midiOutputDeviceSubject$ stream so that all subsequent notes
sent to midiNoteStream$ go to that new device.  I tried this:

```
midiOutputDeviceSubject$.subscribe(outputDevice => {
    midiNoteStream$.subscribe(s => 
        outputDevice.send(s));
    }
});
```

When there is a new device, it adds a new subscription to the note stream, but doesn't remove the old one.  I think there is a simple solution using switchMap, but I just can't see it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This (or something close) should work.

```ts
const midiOutputDeviceSubject$ = new Subject<WebMidi.MIDIOutput>();
const midiNoteStream$ = new Subject<number[]>();

midiOutputDeviceSubject$.pipe(
  switchMap(outputDevice => midiNoteStream$.pipe(
    tap(s => outputDevice.send(s))
  ))
).subscribe();
```

Although a more idiomatic solution might be:

```ts
const midiOutputDeviceSubject$ = new Subject<WebMidi.MIDIOutput>();
const midiNoteStream$ = new Subject<number[]>();

midiNoteStream$.pipe(
  withLatestFrom(midiOutputDeviceSubject$)
).subscribe(([s, outputDevice]) => 
  outputDevice.send(s);
);
```

as this keeps your side-effects contained within `subscribe` rather than polluting a stream. It also doesn't bother with un-subscribing and re-subscribing to the same stream (`midiNoteStream$`). It just maintains these two subscriptions.

But really, it's whichever is easier to understand and maintain.

Comment: That works, thanks!  The second seems clearer so I went with that.